# On Error Goto throws error

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling

There are similar questions about `On Error Goto x` not catching all errors etc, but I've encountered a different problem.

My (Classic ASP) page works fine, most of the time. Some users complain of an error on the page, couldn't duplicate yet.

I tried error handling but `On Error Resume Next` does not help me with this situation and `On Error Goto` causes the page not to work and constantly throw an error (which looks like a 500, but that might be because of handling IIS is doing in background). It happens whether I write `Goto 0` or `Goto [label]` without a difference if the label exists or not.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`On Error GoTo label` is not supported in ASP

you begin an error trapping block  using

`On Error Resume Next` ,

check `Err.Number` to see if an error occurred,

close the block using

`On Error GoTo 0`.

[See this doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300043) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472558/is-try-catch-like-error-handling-possible-in-asp-classic)

Comment: So, I need to `If Err.Number <> 0` after each possible problem. And hope things work if I miss one of those...

Comment: And remember to clear the Err object after a problem, if you want to carry on and check it again later!

Answer (score 3):

Trying to trap every error using On Error Resume Next is not practical in larger ASP pages.

Configure IIS to use a custom error page if a status code 500 is received.  Format the following to suit...

```
Set objASPError = Server.GetLastError

response.write "Category: " & objASPError.Category & _
 "ASPCode: " & objASPError.ASPCode & _
 "Number: " & objASPError.Number & _
 "ASPDescription: " & objASPError.ASPDescription & _
 "Description: " & objASPError.Description & _
 "Source: " & objASPError.Source
```

Comment: It usually ends up without data for some reason

Comment: Some nice include page with a Function/Sub named Catch is quite a nice way to do it.  E.g.
Sub Catch(errNumberExpected, friendlyError, bTerminateExecution, sOptionalRedirect)
etc...

On Error Resume Next

' Your code
Catch 0, "Something went wrong when processing the submission", True, "Home.asp"